# Trying to extract code in the middle of a String

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to extract a code from a string. The string can vary in content and size but I am using Tag words to make the extraction easier. However, I am struggling to nail a particular scenario. Here is the string:

```
({GoldPrice} * 0.376) + {MP.011} + {SilverPrice}
```

What I need to extract is the 011 part of {MP.011}. The keyword will always be "{MP." It's just the code that will change. Also the rest of the expression can change so for example {MP.011} could be at the beginning, end or middle of the string.

I've got close using the following:

```
        int pFrom = code.IndexOf("{MP.") + "{MP.".Length;
        int pTo = code.LastIndexOf("}");
        String result = code.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

However, the result is `011} + {SilverPrice` as it is looking for the last occurrence of }, not the next occurrence. This is where I am struggling.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will it always be 3 characters?  After "MP."?

Comment: C# is not my forte, but couldn't you just loop over the string starting at pFrom? and stop once you encounter an `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the safest option is to use Regex with Negative and Positive Lookahead. This also matches multiple if you need it anyway.

```
  var str3 = @"({GoldPrice} * 0.376) + {MP.011} + {SilverPrice}";
  var result = Regex.Matches(str3, @"(?<=\{MP\.).+?(?=\})");

  foreach (Match i in result)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Simonare. However, this doesn't seem to return a match as a result?

Comment: Appreciate the updated. It now gives a result but it doesn't handle variation of codes, in reality it could be anything after MP. Here is an updated example of the string:

({GoldPrice} * 0.376) + {MP.011M} + {SilverPrice} + {MP.013M}

Comment: Hi Simonare,Getting there! The result is now 011M} + {SilverPrice} + {MP.013M when there should be 2 results "011M" and "013M". Are you able to amend accordingly please?

Comment: If you think this answer is usefull, please consider to upvote and/or tick it as answer. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression to parse that:

```
var str = "({GoldPrice} * 0.376) + {MP.011} + {SilverPrice}";
var number = Regex.Match(str, @"{MP\.(\d+)}")
    .Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        int pFrom = code.IndexOf("{MP.") + "{MP.".Length;
        int pTo = code.IndexOf("}", pFrom); //find index of } after start
        String result = code.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the `.IndexOf(string text,int start)` overload.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string code = "({GoldPrice} * 0.376) + {MP.011} + {SilverPrice}";

    // Step 1. Extract "MP.011"
    int pFrom = code.IndexOf("{MP.");
    int pTo = code.IndexOf("}", pFrom+1);
    string part = code.Substring(pFrom+1, pTo-pFrom-1);
    // Step 2. Extact "011"
    String result = part.Substring(3);
}
```

or you can combine the last statements into

```
    String result = code.Substring(pFrom+1, pTo-pFrom-1).Substring(3);
```